# Is replacing a jamb that had a mezuzah obligates to bless again for the mezuzah

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

A person that replaces [jambs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamb) with new ones. On the old one there was a mezuzah that many years ago he blessed for putting the mezuzah. When placing the mezuzah back on the new jamb should he bless again for putting the mezuzah back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If more than a day has lapsed since it has been taken down one would make a bracha.

Refer to the [Aruch HaShulchan YD 289:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.289.4?lang=bi) who speaks in a different context about taking down mezuzos to be checked. If the mezuzah is returned the same day, no bracha is said, but if a day passes this is deemed a "hefsek", i.e. enough of an interruption to warrant a new bracha - "ואם קבעה לאחר יום – וודאי דמברך"

Comment: Interesting - I was removing mezuzahs each day when builders were in and putting them back at the end of the day and my LOR told me to make a bracha.  I think he said make one even if it falls down and I put it back immediately

Comment: Might it also be that new jambs are like a new doorway, sort of like lifting schach on a sukkah so that would need even if it was a short time according to this?

Comment: This is not obviously analogous. While the jamb was off the door may have been exempt so you aren't returning it to the "same" door.

Comment: Also, this ruling of AhSh for checking mezuzahs is not universally agreed to